# What is wrong with my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I'm wondering what is wrong with my question here: [HttpClient generates SSLException after acquiring new domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24886771/1615903)

In my opinion, I have explained the problem clearly, given plenty of information about my setup, and also explained some of my own efforts on resolving it. Yet, it now has 3 downvotes and 1 upvote. How could I improve the question?

Comment: And to the downvoters of this meta question, what is wrong with this? There are plenty of similar questions in meta asking about a specific question, some of them with plenty of upvotes.

Comment: I agree. This meta question should not have been downvoted. The downvoter should have, at the very least, left a comment explaining why.

Comment: Why did you mark an answer as accepted, when it doesn't seem to answer the question? Why are you asking this question now, almost a year after the question started getting down votes?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that people came to the question, found it was in no way useful to helping them solve their problem, and down-voted it as not useful.

Comment: @TZHX the answer pointed out the SNI which in turn lead me to understand the question "from where does it pick up the old domain name". As to why I'm asking now, does it make any difference? Fact is, the question cannot be deleted since it has an answer, and the 2 downvotes it had until today did not bother me that much. Currently, it has 5 downvotes, and I still have no idea why.

Comment: @StevenJeffries that has been suggested (and rejected) *ad nauseam*; see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/250177. Downvoters **are not required** to leave a comment explaining why they have done so, on Meta or the main site.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think that he meant that it should be mandatory, just that it would have been polite (and useful to me).

Comment: Hard to guess, the question looks fine.  Don't pay too much attention to the meta-effect votes, asking "why" is getting to be politically incorrect these days.  SO users are quite determined to turn SO into a forum.  A completely blind guess is that your question is attracting Google hits that don't have anything to do with Android's httpclient and the visitors are disappointed by what they found.  Consider editing the title, what everybody looks at first, remove Apache.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, removing apache makes sense. This might reduce hits from people searching solutions for problems with apache httpd.

Comment: The question looks and sounds more like a server configuration problem that has nothing to do with programming.  Yes, you're getting errors from an httpclient, but the problem doesn't lie in code, it lies in configuration.  Possibly.

Comment: @Will nope, it was lack of SNI support in the version of Android & HttpClient, I think that does count as programming problem - it could not be resolved by tweaking server settings.

Comment: @1615903 That's information that should probably be included in the question to make it clear that it isn't solved by fixing the server config.